# How i query monogid in active record rails console as to iterate like skipping over a range of records on every iteration

Tags: mongoid

As ruby has function `step(n)` which helps to set increments while iteration, so when using `gem 'mongoid'`. 
How would we do the same since  `monogid` doesn't seem to support  `step(n)`.
Here's the link for [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/querying.html)
Here's the link for [Step function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Range.html#method-i-size)

Answer (score 1):

The Mongoid site docs seem to have left the paging methods out but the embedded documentation covers [`skip`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:skip):

> Skips the provided number of documents.

and [`limit`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:limit):

> Limits the number of documents that are returned from the database.

The [Origin docs](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html) (which is what Mongoid uses for building queries) also cover `skip` and `limit` but you'd need to know where to look or what you're looking for.